# Movie scene where guy in spacesuit accidentally gets his hand cut off

Tags: story-identification, movie

There is a scene from a movie I saw some time in the last 30 years where a guy in a space suit is trying to fix something outside of a spaceship .One of his tools starts to float away and without thinking he grabs it but puts his hand into something like a force field and it cuts his fingers off and the pieces of his hand float off looking a little like jelly beans. He uses the suit to sever the rest of his hand at the wrist to seal the suit and the wound .after that you see him out of the space suit with the metal cap sealing off where his hand once was.Also its wasn't a low budget movie like something from the Scifi channel, it had very high production value to it.

Comment: I'm struggling with this one. Can you have a look through the checklist here ([How to ask a good story-ID question?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)) and see if you can add any extra details.

Comment: I think you dreamt it. I've seen thousands of movies over 40 years but never that. You should write a story around it and publish it on a self publishing site. Good luck!

Comment: I edited the question title because the original one was too generic, it didn't help attract the people who might know the answer.  Feel free to edit the title to something that suits you more.

Comment: It sounded familiar, and I thought it might be "*Bill the Galactic Hero*", but unfortunately it isn't.  But it might be the answer for anyone else looking for a hand cut off story.  In Bill's case, he gets a new arm transplant, but interestingly it was another right arm, giving him the unique ability to shake hands with himself.